# How to show the lua line that has an error using C code

Tags: c, lua

How can I get the line from the lua file that is showing error, I have a table as follows

**My table:**

```
Test = {
    var1 = "...",
    var2 = "...",
    var3 = "..."
};
```

**My Code:**

```
int lua_line(lua_State *L) {
    lua_Debug ar;
    lua_getstack(L, 0, &ar);
    lua_getinfo(L, "l", &ar);
    return ar.currentline;
}

void read_table(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "table.lua") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        ShowError("Error reading 'table.lua'\n");
        return;
    }
    
    lua_getglobal(L, "Test");

    lua_getfield(L, lua_gettop(L), "var1");
    var->one = lua_tointeger(L, 1);
    if(var->one > MAX_VALUE) {
       printf("Value of var1 must not be greater than %d, Error line %d", MAX_VALUE, lua_line(L));
    }
    ....
}
```

When var->one is greater than MAX_VALUE I want to show which lua line should be corrected

I tried to create something using lua_Debug, but without success

When I try to print lua_line the program just stops responding

How should I do to show the line of the lua file with problem?

Comment: I've misunderstood your purpose, you want to get the line number of `var1 = "...",` right? Unfortunately that's not possible, lua can fetch the line which is executing or the line where a function is defined. But it doesn't remember where a variable (especially a table field) is defined after the file/chunk is completely loaded.

Comment: Just raise a Lua error when you get invalid input from Lua. Figuring out how the invalid input got created is the programmer's job.

Comment: @shingo That's exactly what I'm trying to apply, it's a shame it's not possible to get the line that way